# Changing Discussion Folder Names in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is there a way to change the name of a folder within the discussion area of SharePoint 2010? The folder by default is given the name of the discsussion name when it is created, however, if you then change the discussion name, it does not (quite rightly) automatically update the folder name - I would like to though.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a go there, I was able to rename it using SharePoint designer (use the All Files link on the left).

However if you need to do it automatically then you'll have to build an List Item Event Handler, and update the folder name using the API using the ListItemUpdated Event.

Shane